# How to detect duplicates in ArrayList and return new List with duplicated elements

Tags: java, collections

Example:

You recieve an ArrayList with the following content: "A,B,A,B,C,A,F,Z,C,H"

New output list should only contain duplicated elements: "A,B,C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a frequency hashmap to keep track of count, and use that map to filter out the duplicates

```
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("A");
        list.add("F");
        list.add("Z");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("H");
        Map<String, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s: list) {
            if(freqMap.containsKey(s)){
                freqMap.put(s, freqMap.get(s)+1);
            } else {
                freqMap.put(s, 1);
            }
        }

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: freqMap.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue() > 1){
                result.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first if statement may be `freqMap.compute(s, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);`.

Comment: @saka1029, or `freqMap.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` collection to identify the duplicate because set is an unsorted list of distinct elements. If Set's `add()` method returns `false` that means element already exists in list.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("A");
        list.add("F");
        list.add("Z");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("H");

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> duplicateElements = new HashSet<>();
        for (String element : list) {
            if (!set.add(element)) {
                duplicateElements.add(element);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Duplicate Elements : " + duplicateElements);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
Set.copyOf( list ).stream().filter( s -> list.indexOf( s ) != list.lastIndexOf( s ) ).sorted().toList()
```

Or, reformatted:

```java
Set
        .copyOf( 
            list     // List.of( "A,B,A,B,C,A,F,Z,C,H".split( "," ) )
        )
        .stream()
        .filter( 
            s -> list.indexOf( s ) != list.lastIndexOf( s ) 
        )
        .sorted()
        .toList()
```

> [A, B, C]

## Details

Make a list from your input string. Using `String#split` generates an array of the parts. Feeding that array to `List.of` produces an unmodifiable `List` object.

```
List < String > list = List.of( "A,B,A,B,C,A,F,Z,C,H".split( "," ) );
```

Next, we need a distinct collection of the letters, eliminating duplicates. A `Set` by definition has no duplicates. Passing our `List` to `Set.copyOf` produces an unmodifiable `Set` object.

```
Set < String > distinct = Set.copyOf( list );
```

We want to examine each value from the distinct set, to see if is in the original list more than once.

We know each element is in the list at least once. So we can use `List#indexOf` to get the index (zero-based position) within the list. And we can get `List#lastIndexOf` to get the position of the last duplicate. If the two calls return the *same* number, we know there is only one occurrence. If the two calls return *different* index numbers, we know we have more than one. So we make a predicate test comparing those two calls for each `String` element: `s -> list.indexOf( s ) != list.lastIndexOf( s )`.

Rather than write loops, we can use streams. We call `Set#stream` to generate a stream of the distinct set’s elements.

We filter that stream for the elements where the first and last index found are different, while ignoring those that flunk our predicate test. Of those that pass the predicate test, first we sort, then collect into a `List`.

```java
List < String > dups =
        distinct
                .stream()
                .filter( s -> list.indexOf( s ) != list.lastIndexOf( s ) )
                .sorted()
                .toList();  // Before Java 16, replace with `.collect( Collectors.toList() );`.
```

> list = [A, B, A, B, C, A, F, Z, C, H]
>
> distinct = [A, H, F, Z, C, B]
>
> dups = [A, B, C]

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dup(array) {
  var tab = array[0].split(",");
  var obj = {};
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    if (!obj[tab[i]]) {
      obj[tab[i]] = 1;
    } else {
      obj[tab[i]]++;
    }
  }
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] > 1) {
      result.push(key);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative, you can implement the same algorithm with streams:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting())
    .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .toList();
```